# Mongoose async promise don't seem to work

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a little trouble using the async' with mongoose. Basically my code is the following :

```
function() {
   SchemaOne.findById(fooIdOne).exec().then( x => {
      // Some first instructions
      myCollection.foreach( y => {
         SchemaTwo.findById(fooIdTwo).exec().then( z => {
            // Some second instructions
         });
      });
   }).then(() => {
      // Code to execute after
   });
}
```

Here I would like the "first instructions" and "second instructions" to be made BEFORE the "code to execute after", but the last "then" don't seem to wait for the second instructions to be made.

Could use a little help !
Many thanks ! Kev'.

Comment: you never return this promise, so the last then will execute immediately after the first then

Comment: So here I should find a way to put my "SchemaTwo.findById" at the same level than the "SchemaOne.findById" in order to fix this ? Because I need to have this second query into the foreach wich make it a bit more complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `forEach` call is executed synchronously and you don't return a promise in the `then` callback.

You should collect the promises that are created in the loop, and return a `Promise.all` of those.

```
function() {
   SchemaOne.findById(fooIdOne).exec().then( x => {
      // Some first instructions
      let promises = [];
      myCollection.foreach( y => {
         promises.push(SchemaTwo.findById(fooIdTwo).exec().then( z => {
            // Some second instructions
         }));
      });
      return Promise.all(promises);
   }).then(() => {
      // Code to execute after
   });
}
```

Comment: Okay I was seeing the async problem but could not find the code to fix it, many thanks !